# x86 NASM Assembly - Comparing the input with integer values

Tags: assembly, if-statement, x86, nasm

I am trying to compare an input data with a integer value

here the basic code I am using

```
section .bss
    input resb 2

section .text
global _start
_start:
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, input
    mov edx, 5
    int 0x80
    mov eax, [input]
    cmp eax, 20 // This is what I cannot get to work, it never compares it to 20 even if i enter 20 as input
    je next
```

All I really want to know is how to do the If statement in Assembly to compare input with an integer.

I would really apprecaite any help with this, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing `eax` (the first byte of input`) with the integer`20`. This is the DC4 control character, which is almost certainly not your input.

If you want to compare to the number 20, then you will need to convert input to a number first (and accept more than one character of input).

Comment: Okay, is there a quick way to convert the input to a number? or is there a way to convert 20 into a comparairable value?

other codes I tried were:

mov eax, [num1]
sub eax, '0'
cmp eax, 20

I just don't get it how to convert the input to look like the integer value

Comment: The `atoi` libc function may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code...

```
section .bss
    input resb 2

section .text
global _start
_start:
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, input
    mov edx, 5
    int 0x80
    mov eax, dword[input];dword is require for double word size
    cmp eax, 20 
    je next
```

Comment: I fixed your post. Please consider using code blocks where appropriate in the future.